# How to use Python re to parse this string in to list of multiple key value pairs?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of in Python

```
str1 = 'abc(1),bcd(xxx),ddd(dfk dsaf)'
```

How to use re to parse it into an object say 'results' so I can do something like:

```
for k,v in results:
   print('key = %r, value = %r', (k, v))
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking? Like... `key=abc value=1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, using `re.findall`:

```
>>> str1 = 'abc(1),bcd(xxx),ddd(dfk dsaf)'
>>> results = re.findall(r'(\w+)\(([^)]+)\),?',str1)
for k,v in results:
    print('key = %r, value = %r' % (k, v))
...     
key = 'abc', value = '1'
key = 'bcd', value = 'xxx'
key = 'ddd', value = 'dfk dsaf'
```

Pass it to `dict()` if you want a dict:

```
>>> dict(results)
{'bcd': 'xxx', 'abc': '1', 'ddd': 'dfk dsaf'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `finditer`:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'(\w+)\((.*?)\)')
>>> {x.group(1):x.group(2) for x in p.finditer(str1)}
{'bcd': 'xxx', 'abc': '1', 'ddd': 'dfk dsaf'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could, at a pinch, do it without resorting to regex

```
 str1 = 'abc(1),bcd(xxx),ddd(dfk dsaf)'
 results = [x.split('(') for x in str1.split(',')]
 results = [(x, y.rstrip(')')) for x, y in results]
 print results
 [('abc', '1'), ('bcd', 'xxx'), ('ddd', 'dfk dsaf')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = 'abc(1),bcd(xxx),ddd(dfk dsaf)'

import re
d = dict(re.findall('(\w+)\((.*?)\)', str1))
# {'bcd': 'xxx', 'abc': '1', 'ddd': 'dfk dsaf'}

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    # do whatever
```